# facebook login permissions not displayed for some users

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using Facebook js sdk, requesting the 'user_birthday' permission.

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            _fbLoginCallBack(response);
        } else {
            var permissions = {
                scope : 'email,user_birthday'
            };
            FB.login(responseCallback, permissions);
        }
    });
```

I have made the app and all its live features available to the general public.

**The code works If I am logged with the same account I created the app with, but when try using different account, it doesn't display the permissions, and the returned JSON is missing the email and the birthday fields**

What's happening ?

Comment: Your app must be in `review` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Login Review**
You might need to do a Login review.
Review is not required to ask for the three basic permissions: public_profile, user_friends and email. In order to use Facebook Login in your app and access ***additional*** elements of a person's Facebook profile, you will need to submit your app for review. If your app is not approved or you don't submit for review, people will not be able to use Facebook Login in your app.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review

**2. Make app live**
You need to make the app and all its live features available to the general public. This can be done by making the app live by going to https://developers.facebook.com, select Apps --> Your App Name --> ***'Status & Review'***.